# Changing connection params when using pass-through query

Tags: ms-access-2003, pass-through

I have an Access 2003 application that I would like to create reports for using stored procedures via pass-through queries. Everything works fine with one exception. When I specify the stored procedure to use for the pass-through query I have to choose a DSN to provide the database connection info. I need to be able to change the connection info for the stored procedure used in the pass-through query **via code**. This is so I can switch to development, production, testing environments from within the application.

Currently all of my data access (additions, updates, edits) uses ADO and I build the connection strings via VBA code. I am unsure how how to change the connection info of the pass-through queries via code. Any thoughts? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the Connect property of your pass-through query.  You can change Connect with VBA.  This procedure switches between prod and dev database connections.

```
Public Sub SwitchPassThroughConnection(ByVal pQuery As String, ByVal pTarget As String)
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim strConnect As String
    Dim blnError As Boolean

    Set db = CurrentDb()

    Select Case pTarget
    Case "dev"
        strConnect = "ODBC;DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};DATABASE=dev;SERVER=cmpq;" & _
            "PORT=5432;UID=hans;PWD=changeme;CA=d;A6=;A7=100;A8=4096;" & _
            "B0=255;B1=8190;BI=0;C2=dd_;CX=1b502bb;A1=7.4"
    Case "prod"
        strConnect = "ODBC;DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};DATABASE=prod;SERVER=cmpq;" & _
            "PORT=5432;UID=hans;PWD=changeme;CA=d;A6=;A7=100;A8=4096;" & _
            "B0=255;B1=8190;BI=0;C2=dd_;CX=1b502bb;A1=7.4"
    Case Else
        blnError = True
        MsgBox "Unrecognized target."
    End Select

    If Not blnError Then
        Set qdef = db.QueryDefs(pQuery)
        qdef.Connect = strConnect
        qdef.Close
    End If
    Set qdef = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```